# How do I define a Reverse Proxy to a docker windows container

Tags: docker

I am run a docker windows container on windows 10 anniversary edition and am looking to setup IIS as a reverse proxy to the container.  Per https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2016/05/25/windows-nat-winnat-capabilities-and-limitations/ it seems to suggest that it is an impossibility as it is impossible to reference the internal NAT range using local host.  Which leaves a dynamically assigned IP address which can only be discover by running a docker inspect command after running the image.  I am hoping there is a more efficient way that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved this problem by assigning an IP address on the default subnet to each Windows container and exporting port 80 out of the container.  This gave us a stable address to put into an ARR Reverse proxy rule. For example the following creates a container at the address 172.20.118.129 and then verifies the container is running at the requested address.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run -d --name myservice --ip=172.20.118.129 microsoft/iis:nanoserver
7d20d8a131805727868ddf85f7c1f455fa2489bb2607b250e694a9e530a61302
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" myservice
172.20.118.129
```

Comment: Do you think that your solution is fine also for production deployments? How do you have configured ARR? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

We also used a fixed ip address on our containers but we used another container with `nginx` to do the reverse proxy. The idea is that on our Container Host (Windows Server 2016) we only install Docker and nothing else. All configuration is done in the containers. This way we can easily migrate to another host.

This is the Dockerfile for the nginx proxy

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ARG NgInxVersion="1.13.5"
ENV NgInxZipUrl="http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NgInxVersion}.zip"

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:NgInxZipUrl -UseBasicParsing -Outfile c:\\nginx.zip
RUN Expand-Archive -Path c:\\nginx.zip -DestinationPath c:\\nginx

WORKDIR "c:\\nginx\\nginx-${NgInxVersion}"

COPY ./nginx.conf conf\\nginx.conf

ENTRYPOINT powershell .\\nginx.exe
```

Notice that the `nginx.conf` is copied to the `nginx` configuration folder. It contains the reverse proxy settings. Extract from `http` node for one of our sites:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  somesite.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://172.22.108.6/;
    }
}
```

The `nginx` container should be run with `-p 80:80`

When we add new containers we run a powershell script that updates the nginx.conf and reloads nginx. (this will be rare)

Example:

1. A user browses to http://somesite.mydomain.com
2. Our DNS redirects somesite.mydomain.com to ip of our Container Host
3. Since port `80` is exposed to nginx container, request goes there
4. nginx will proxy the request to `172.22.108.6`
5. User sees the webpage running on container with ip `172.22.108.6`

Comment: You could also create a container with IIS and ARR to replace the nginx (guide here https://chris.59north.com/post/Combining-Windows-Server-2016-Container-ASPNET-5-and-Application-Request-Routing-(ARR)-using-Docker). But I found that nginx was more lightweight and easier to setup.

Comment: The original question asked for how to use IIS as a reverse proxy. Saying "I used NGINX!" is helpful, but really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BryanRayner The title is `How do I define a Reverse Proxy to a docker windows container` and the OP mentions he is looking into setting this up with IIS. I am suggesting an alternative approach.
I also looked into setting this up with IIS but doing it in nginx is less complex and can be done within a container, you do not need to change the configuration of the host. In my opinion this is the preferred solution and that is why a made an effort to add my answer.

Comment: When I try to use the above on FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016 it crashes on startup.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Rubanov That ARR idea doesn't help because ARR itself does not run inside a container